# How to decrypt a gpg file?

Tags: gnupg, sha256

I have a gpg file and a sha256 file. When I try to decrypt the gpg file using the *gpg - d file.gpg* command, it says that there is no secret key. I am absolutely new to this so I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Be carefull with gpg versions, if you have upgraded from gpg 1 to gpg 2 you may need to export/import your old keys, I had problems decrypting files encrypted with different gpg versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG works by using two different kinds of keys: a private key and a public key. When you use the software, you create both a public and private key (called a keypair). You make your public key, well, public. Anyone can use it to encrypt arbitrary data, but that data can only be *decrypted* by using the corresponding private (aka secret) key. If it says there is no secret key, that means the file was not encrypted with your public key. In other words, it is not intended for you and you will not be able to decrypt it. You can only decrypt things that have been encrypted for *you*.

Is it possible that you want to *verify* the file instead of decrypt it? Since you mention a file with SHA-256 hashes, is this some sort of software you are downloading that came with a `.sig` file? If so, you need to import the public key with `--import` (you can usually find it on the download website for whatever you downloaded) and then use `--verify` instead of `-d`. See also:

- [Instructions for encrypting and decrypting](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html)
- [Instructions for signing and verifying](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html)